# NullReference Exception throws while connecting to MsSql

Tags: c#

```
using MERCURY.Database;

namespace MERCURY.Service {
    public class CommonWindowsService : ServiceBase {
        internal static MercuryDatabase Database;
.
.
Database = new MercuryDatabase(Settings.Default.MercuryDatabase);
```

in the same namespace I am trying to call this:

```
CommonWindowsService.Database.CbWorkerStart(_updateThread.ManagedThreadId, _updateThread.Name);
```

but, it throws null reference exception in CommonWindowsService.Database.
why?

Comment: did you check whether `_updateThread` been initialize? by looking at this only thing I can suspect is `_updateThread` is `null` !!

Comment: what we can understand from this code ? add some stacktrace and source of error

Comment: it was working fine, but now does not!

Comment: For the code line `CommonWindowsService.Database.CbWorkerStart()` to work, you need to have the static `Database` initialized... makes sure its instanciation has been called first before executing that line. Secondly, like @huMptyduMpty stated, check whether `_updateThread` is null or not.

Comment: There is not much info here; the obvious thing to do is to *look at what piece is `null` when it throws*; most likely `_updateThread` or `Settings.Default`; use the debugger, Luke!